# Эмулятор андроид на линукс

Tags: android, linux, эмулятор

Подскажите, есть ли на линукс эмуляторы, подобные LDPlayer, NOX или BlueStacks для винды ?
Именно полноценные эмуляторы с плеймаркетом, с настраиваемым управлением клавиатурой и мышью, макросами, записью видео и т.д.

То что мне удалось найти - либо какой то колхоз с непонятными возможностями или функционалом, либо для какого то узкого применения.

Comment: для разработки или игровой?

Comment: Игровой. Что б была возможность настраивать управление с мышки и клавиатуры.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration пропробуй настроить ускорение видео вручную

Comment: Это для чего нужно, не могу понять ?